# Azure Access token with narrower scope

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

I have question about getting access token, with refresh token with narrower scope.

I send  this request to azure token endpoint

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scopehttps%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi%2FReport.Read.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi%2FDashboard.Read.All%20https%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi%2FDataset.Read.All
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fanalysis.windows.net%2Fpowerbi%2Fapi
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
```

If I remember correctly, OAuth2 does allow this operation. I would like to ask whether im doing something wrong, or azure doesnt implemnt this funcionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Azure AD, the scope parameter defines the minimum scopes you want to have in the token.
So the token can still contain other permissions if they have been consented. 
As far as I know, there is no way to control this behaviour.

Comment: Well, thats unfortunate ... do you know if i can get atleast refresh token with lower permisions ? :) ... What i want to achieve is that im sendig access token to browser from server (i didnt find waiy to show power bi reports wihout access token im using power bi js library). Otherwise i will have to make another app which will issue lowered tokens.

Comment: No, you'll get all the scopes granted to the app by that user / admin. AAD product team is aware of this limitation though.